# MySQL - Ranking with millions of entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm working on a project and right now I'm implementing a leaderboard. Before I start working on it, I need some advices for better practice of my leaderboard's structure.

First of all the leaderboard will be displayed on two pages, the one is on the home page of each player's which will contain the first 10 teams (same 10 teams for all players) and the other leaderboard will be in the leaderboard's page, which there, will have all the teams with sorting functionalities.

The structure of the leaderboard of each row is the following: 
• ranking position 
• team name 
• team value 
• total of the games the team won 
• total of the games the team defeated 
• total of the games the team had draw 
• sum of the goals the team has made 
• sum of the goals the team has conceded 
• the last 4 game results of the team

Below is my database's tables

challenges table

```
CREATE TABLE `challenges` (
  id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'challenge_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `challanges_id_index` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

challenges results

```
CREATE TABLE `challenges_results` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `challenge_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goals` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `result` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `challenge_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

On challenges results result column can be W for wins, D for draws and L for defeats

team values

```
CREATE TABLE `team_values` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` double(15,8) DEFAULT '1500.00000000',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

team

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `founded` date NOT NULL,
  `residense_city_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `primary_color` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `secondary_color` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `teams_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  KEY `teams_id_index` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

One team can have many values (teams_values) but only the recent will be displayed. 
One team can be in many challenges.
One team can have many results from different challenges.

The leaderboard will work as follow. The teams will be sorted with the highest values from teams_values table. That value is calculated and stored every time the team is having a challenge.

In case where two or more teams have the same value we need to apply the following three rules. The rules also needs to be executed one by one, for example if I run the first rule and still there are teams which are equal also on value and goals scored then I will apply the second rule and so on.
• Best offense (higher Number of goals scored)
• Best Defense (Less Number of goals conceded)
• The team with the most wins in the games between them

So I came with three solutions which still I don't know which one is the better and if there is a better from the three.

The first option that I though is to use options like inner join, union etc to collect the information from the tables and apply the rules on the same SQL query. So every time that I want to view the leaderboard, I will execute this SQL. The problem with this solution is that I don't know how effective will be in case that we want the leaderboard to be always up to date with the latest results. Because imaging having 10k visitors per day and everyone executing this query.

Second option is to collect the information and in case of duplicate values, I will use PHP to get the duplicate teams, apply the rules and then based on the results of the rules swipe the teams in the array. From performance site I don't know how effective is this option.

Third solution is to create another table called leaderboard which I will store all this information in case the team doesn't exist or I will update the record if exist based on the results of the latest challenge e.g increasing the goals if the team scored. Then I will use only the leaderboard table for filtering the data and printing the ranking of the teams. I believe this option is better because I need to deal only with one table and I will update the record only when a team finished a challenge.

We will use cache, but for now we are thinking that the leaderboard should be always up to date and not updating it once a day.

Which one is better solution and why and in case of a better solution I'm open for suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you have the hardware capacity to regenerate the leaderboard on the fly, then do it. If you have limited hardware capacity, a cache approach makes sense.

Comment: Also, using PHP to further filter your datasets is an extra layer of computation. If you can at all help it, try keep all your data query-specific functionality as SQL code. Otherwise you run resources against it that process and return a dataset, only to re-evaluate that dataset using PHP-based rules in a different way.

Comment: For the beginning will be on a shared account on vps. @KarlBuys

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running on a shared account on a virtual private server, the chances are very going you're going to theoretically run into cases where you contend for the use of server resources, disk usage, memory usage, cpu processing power.

First and foremost, try do all your database calculations in MySQL, and only return the data to PHP once you've completed all operations on them. MySQL is optimised for the job, whereas PHP is better at general computing problems.

Your one option to take some load off the server would be to use PHP to create a webpage that is viewable in the browser, every single time the leaderboard is updated. That way, you run through calculations only once every time the leaderboard needs to be updated.

If I was building the system and the system was never going to reach enterprise-grade level, but instead remain small and functional, I would write a PHP script early on, because you can save a lot of processing power that way alone.

For what it's worth, if the server is well configured, you shouldn't be worried about getting 10k user requests a day, unless your code is really terribly written.

EDIT: As an afterthought, you can install a program like https://memcached.org/, which caches your SQL data in RAM. Sites like LiveJournal and Wordpress use it, but you'd need to configure it in a way that works for the rest of the vps users unless the box is really high spec.

Comment: The product is based on laravel and we will use redis. So you are saying that there is not need of creating a new table with aggregate values?

Comment: Redis would be a bad fit, except in very specific cases, like when you're querying a remote server. It's like using a second database on top of your MySQL database to store the first database's results. I would suggest you try build it without the aggregate table and see if you're happy with how responsive it is. If it isn't responsive enough, then look to optimise it

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I will start using SQL queries and if it is takes time I will optimise it.